# Не работает изменение переменной при нажатии на див

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код:

```
img = 0;
function SaveFon() {
    localStorage.setItem("object1", img)
}

document.querySelector('.but3').onclick = function () {
    var img = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object1"))
    if (img == 1) {
        img = 20;
    } else {
        img--;
    }
    SaveFon();
}

document.querySelector('.but4').onclick = function () {
    var img = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object1"))
    if (img == 20) {
        img = 1;
    } else {
        img++;
    }
    SaveFon();
}

document.querySelector('.pic_pr1').onclick = function () {
    img = 1;
    SaveFon();
}
document.querySelector('.pic_pr2').onclick = function () {
    img = 2;
    SaveFon();
}
document.querySelector('.pic_pr3').onclick = function () {
    img = 3;
    SaveFon();
}
document.querySelector('.pic_pr4').onclick = function () {
    img = 4;
    SaveFon();
}
```

Если нажимать на дивы "`pic_pr1`"..."`pic_pr4`".. то всё работает, переменная равняется той, что надо. И меняется фон сайта. Но есть еще два дива (типа кнопки "назад" и "вперед"), чтобы не нажимать на любой див, а пролистывать все как бы. Так вот, почему-то эти два дива "`but3`" и "`but4`" не выполняют то, что нужно. А именно менять переменную. Например, если изначально нажать на "Вперед", то переменная должна стать "`1`", если нажать еще раз, то "`2`".. соответственно "Назад" будет отнимать по "`1`". Но это не работает. Также, нужно чтобы если сначала выбрал див и переменная стала, например "`3`", а потом решил воспользоваться дивами "Назад" и "Вперед", то отсчет уже пошёл с "`3`" соответственно.

Comment: У вас названия переменных смешались

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Дело в том, что вам нужно менять глобальную переменную. Вы ее создаете так.

```
img = 0;
```

и потом сохроняете так

```
function SaveFon() {
    localStorage.setItem("object1", img) // глобальная
}
```

а когда вы ее меняете вы создаете локальную переменную, которая будет жить только внутри функции. Чтобы использовать глобальную переменную избавтесь от ключегого слова `var`

```
document.querySelector('.but3').onclick = function () {
    var img = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object1")) // локальная
    //img = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object1")) // глобальная
    if (img == 1) {
        img = 20;
    } else {
        img--;
    }
    SaveFon();
}
```

Comment: Да, в этом и была проблема, спасибо!)